# Bootstrap Grid Jumping between screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a grid of buttons using bootstrap, however, when I change screen size on a desktop the layout jumps to the new position, i have seen in other questions that the answer was to change it to continer-fluid and row-fluid within the div, however this did not help.

My CSS and HTML  is

```css
.top-buffer
{ margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Turn off zooming on Mobile page-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">


</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<p> This is the nav bar</p>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid">

         <div class="row-fluid top-buffer"></div> <!-- this row is added in for iPhone Spacing. -->
         <div class="row-fluid top-buffer"><!-- open the first row int he grid-->

             <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">               <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" >

                    <form action="page2JobMainMenu.html">
                    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block"> Job </button>

                    </form>

                </div>

              <div class=" col-sm-4 col-xs-4">

                <form action= "page3CreateQuote.html">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block">
                Quote </button>
                </form>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">

                <form action="page4FinanceMainMenu.html">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block">
                Finance</button>
                </form>
              </div>
        </div><!--close off the cold md 4 div-->
        </div><!-- Close the first row-->

          </div><!-- Close the Fluid Container -->
  </div><!--Close the Jumbotron-->
```

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by jumping?

Comment: Describe your issue please, Taking a guess at what is happening that you don't want to happen, is that `col-md-4` will change from a `float: left; width: 33.33%` to `float: none; width:100%;` when your screen size becomes smaller than `768px`.

Comment: @fyrye yes that is correct.

Comment: To elaborate on fyrye's comment. This behaviour is happening because of class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" on the parent div from the divs containing the buttons. The md-classes do not apply on screen sizes below 992px. If you replace it by class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" it should do the exact same across all screen sizes. I do recommend reading the bootstrap documentation on this for a better understanding: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: On a side note you could omit all the col-sm-4 classes in your code, since they do the same as col-xs-4.

Comment: For sanity sake, I referenced Bootstrap 4 grid styling rules: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: Thats great, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically works as is.  Using `col-xs-4` ensures that at even the smallest resolution the buttons will still retain their 3-column layout.  It's not necessary to use `col-md-4` in this instance, and `.row-fluid` has not been in use since Bootstrap 2.  `.center-block` is also unnecessary as `.btn-block` is designed to treat Bootstrap Buttons as full-width elements.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
   <form action="page2JobMainMenu.html"><button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Button</button></form>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-4">
   <form action="page3CreateQuote.html"><button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Button</button></form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
   <form action="page4FinanceMainMenu.html"><button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Button</button></form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Note: If you can avoid using the `<button>` within a `<form>` you can make use of Bootstrap's `.btn-group` component for greater functionality.

Comment: I was going to use md to keep the buttons central on larger screens.  But that might be making the jump happen.  Thanks Robert.

Comment: `col-md-4` wasn't doing anything that `col-xs-4` wasn't already providing.  Both column calls specify using 1/3 of the total container.  You generally only provide another column style when there is an actually change (ie. `col-sm-6 col-md-4`)